# Two-sided document: reverse page margins for hardcopy

Tags: margins, lyx, koma-script, double-sided

### Background

Wrote a manual in LyX. The PDF is two-sided. Using KOMA Script v2. The pages are 8.5" x 11".

### Problem

The spacing on the margins is not printer-friendly, it is reversed:

[image]

Since this page is an even-numbered page (4), the print shop said that the extra space must be on the right-hand side. The extra space (for binding) is currently on the left-hand side (of even pages).

### Question

How can the margins be swapped so that the larger space is on the right (for even page numbers) while maintaining the same total margin space?

### Ideas

- Tried adding a blank page to the beginning of the manual.
- `\KOMAoptions{BCOR=3cm}\recalctypearea`

The latter results in the margins having been flipped around, but with different spacing.

Thank you!

Comment: BTW for non-KOMA docs using [geometry](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package there is `bindingoffset` option, which respects `oneside` or `twoside` styles.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is normal that the outside margins are larger than the inside margins. However, KOMA-script/typearea supports the specification of a binding correction. That is, specifying how much space will be lost on the inside of the pages due to binding. The effect is that it shifts the text to the outside by that amount.

You specify the binding correction by passing the `BCOR` option to the documentclass: `\documentclass[BCOR=3cm]{scrbook}`. Alternatively, you can also add `\KOMAoptions{BCOR=3cm}\recalctypearea` to your preamble.

---

Edit: One way to switch margins is to add the following to your preamble:

```
\let\tmp\oddsidemargin
\let\oddsidemargin\evensidemargin
\let\evensidemargin\tmp
\reversemarginpar
```

This will exchange the margin sizes and print marginpars on the inside. I don't know whether that switching has any other unintended side-effects.

Comment: @Dave, well typearea tries to calculate the page layout according to what its author thinks is the best way (the exact algorithm is described in the koma manual). You can try setting a higher number of division (by passing something like 'DIV=10' to the documentclass). If you want absolute control over the margin sizes, the koma manual says that you should just use the `geometry` package, which lets you set specific margin sizes.

Comment: You are right that even numbered pages should be on the left. But typically the outside margin is the larger one (just look at any book). So for even numbered pages the right margin should be larger.

Comment: Sorry, i meant to say: ”... for even numbered pages the *left* margin should be larger”.

Comment: @Dave: Shouldn't they just tell you what binding correction they need and leave the rest up to you? I don't see any easy and non-hackish way to switch margins in KOMA-Script, but I am really no expert on what KOMA can do.

Comment: @Caramdir: I cracked open The Mythical Man-Month. Indeed, just as you said, and just as shown in the figure.

Comment: @Caramdir: I looked at The Pramatic Programmer. It is printed as the print shop said. The print shop also said that it prints hundreds of tech. manuals a year and this was the first they saw with the margins flipped around (as per KOMA's defaults).

Comment: @Caramdir: Coders At Work and Object-Oriented Software Construction are also the opposite of KOMA Script. The O'Reilly series I have (vi and iPhone Game Dev.) have 50/50 margins. Some of the other tech. manuals have different margins altogether. Is there a standard at all? ;-)

Comment: @Dave: Interesting. I guess typesetting conventions can differ radically between fields.

Comment: @Dave: Please don't accept yet, I'd be interested if anyone nows how to do such a layout with KOMA. I think KOMA is predominantly used in Europe, so wait a bit for the Europeans to wake up again.

Comment: @Dave: I tried to read `typearea.sty`. While I can't say I understand everything it does, it gave me one rather obvious solution to the problem (see the updated answer). Since I have never tried to access layout parameters directly before, I don't know whether this has any side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Even numbered pages would be inverted margin-wise and page numbers would appear on the ‘inner' side of the page. For me though, the chapter title in the header was on the wrong side as well. E.g. on page 4 it read "Chapter 1.4 xxx" on the left (inner) side and since I put my pagenumbers in the footer those too appeared at the page's inner margin.

So in my case, everything including margins, page header and footer was simply inverted. However, neither my table of contents, nor list of tables and figures were inverted, so I concluded there was something immediately after `\listoftables` that was causing the inverted margins etc. What I then found was a `\clearpage` which I put there so that the next chapter doesn't start on the same page as the list of tables.

Look for a `\clearpage` in your `twoside`-enabled document and remove it or replace it with a `\cleardoublepage` if you absolutely need it because `\clearpage` will cause everything to invert.

Answer (score 2):

The default layout is exactly right. The idea is that when you open the book flat on the table, the white space at the borders and in the middle (between the even and odd pages of the text) are the same width (for balance).
The memoir documentation (memman.pdf) and I believe the KOMA bundle documentation also explain all this in great length.

Answer (score 2):

From main menu:

```
Document>Settings...>Page Layout
```

Then click on checkbox for "Two-sided document".

Regards

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.